# "Even when pets is not my thing…" Is this grammatical?

Tags: verb-agreement

My friend just posted a picture with a soft toy and captioned it:

**"Even when pets is not my thing, you can always pose with soft toys!"**

I want to know if that sentence is grammatically correct. I don't know why but this sentence just doesn't look grammatical to me. Should not it be "pets are" and "Even though" ?

It's my first time posting a question here, sorry if I've not followed the guidelines.

Comment: Please keep the pronoun person constant.That's what tells your gut that the sentence isn't alright.I'd do it like this: "Even when keeping pets isn't my thing,I could always pose with soft toys!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that pets is a plural noun so use 'are' and and when is not the appropriate word to link it shoud be some like Eventhough or Though.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are right that it should be *pets are*, not *pets is*

Secondly, neither *even though* nor *even when* works here. *Even though*  means something like *despite the fact*. For example:

- Even though (despite the fact) I like pets, I don't want them in my
  bedroom.

It does not make sense to write:

- Despite the fact that pets are not my thing, you can always pose with soft toys!

*Even when* means something like *even at the times when (something happens)* . For example:

- Even when (even at the times when) my pets chew up my soft toys, I don't scold them.

So this doesn't work either:

- Even at the times when pets are not my thing, you can always pose with soft toys!

The most natural way for your friend to express the idea is:

- If pets are not your thing, you can always pose with soft toys.

Or:

- Since pets are not my thing, I (always) pose with soft toys.